# Fill an Image using an ImageMask Swift

Tags: swift, mask, layer, cgcontext, clip

I am trying to fiddle out how to fill a PNG which center is transparent with a color.
I made you a preview to visualize what I'm not able to explain :D

[image]

The "Shield Icon" are only a stroke. The have no background wether on the inside nor on the outside.

I want to call a function like

```
func fillShield(percentage: CGFLoat) {
     ...
     //code needed to fill the shield
}
```

How do I manage to get something like that working in swift?

Cheers, Niklas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a PNG do you have the original SVG (or can you get one).  If so, I suggest getting PaintCode, which will take this SVG and give you code to draw it with bezier curves -- from there it's very easy to also fill it partially -- you can use the bezier and a rectangle as a mask.

If not, can you modify the png such that it isn't transparent on the outside? If so, you only need to draw the green rectangle underneath and it will show through.

If you need a transparent outside (to overlay on a background), make two copies of the PNG, one with a transparent inside, and one with a transparent outside.  Use the first one to make the progress image and then copy the Alpha channel from the second one into the result.

CoreImage and CoreGraphics have the functions you need to do each part -- here is a link for understanding how to get to the pixels (for copying channels):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/69855/image-processing-in-ios-part-1-raw-bitmap-modification

EDIT: Elaboration.  You need two images

1. Image 1 is the shield with a white opaque on the outside and transparent on the inside
2. Image 2 is the shield with white opaque on the inside and transparent on the outside

Steps:

1. Draw a green rectangle with the height determined by progress an the bottom set to the inside bottom of the shield onto an image using CoreGraphics
2. Draw Image 1 on top of that.  You now have an image with the shield filled with green progress and white on the outside.
3. Copy the alpha channel of Image 2 onto the result of Step 2. You now have an image with the progress filled in and a transparent outside.

Comment: Can't I just mask the Fill to the Bounds of the Shield (with the 2nd PNG you were talking about) and then add the PNG I already have on top of it? And if so, how do I apply this mask to the Fill? Creating the 2nd PNG is no problem. I don't have PaintCode nor an SVG

Comment: Drawing an image with transparency on top of an image without does not make the bottom image transparent.  You need to copy the alpha channel.  I will try to elaborate in the answer.